Error jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction Upgrading springframework from 3.1.11 to 3.3.3
Getting the below error while upgrade the springframework from 3.1.11 to 3.3.3
jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:303) ~[spring-orm-6.1.12.jar!/:6.1.12]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy161.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.greenqloud.usage.nfsaas.dao.usage.AggregationLockManager.insertLock(AggregationLockManager.java:52) ~[!/:1.0.0]
    at com.greenqloud.usage.nfsaas.dao.usage.AggregationLockManager.aquireLock(AggregationLockManager.java:31) ~[!/:1.0.0]
    at com.greenqloud.usage.nfsaas.AggregationPipeline.processMetrics(AggregationPipeline.java:136) ~[!/:1.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.12.jar!/:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) ~[spring-messaging-6.1.12.jar!/:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:75) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:278) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandlerAndProcessResult(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:225) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:149) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1682) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1604) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1592) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1583) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListenerAndHandleException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1528) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.lambda$executeListener$8(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:499) ~[micrometer-observation-1.13.3.jar!/:1.13.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1506) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1082) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1018) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1322) ~[spring-rabbit-3.1.7.jar!/:3.1.7]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

I have tried putting the @Transactional before methods with some comination but the same error is coming.
Using jakarta from org.glassfish jakarta.el(4.0.2)

paste method and code in which you are getting error
